# Wordpress Tag Cloud args (font-size) not working since wp update 4.9

Tags: widgets

the following filter worked fine:

```
function set_widget_tag_cloud_args($args) {
$my_args = array('smallest' => 16,
               'largest' => 24,
               'orderby'=>'name',
               'order'=>'RAND',
               'unit'=>'px',
               'separator' => '<span style="font-size:16px">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>',);
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $my_args );
return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args','set_widget_tag_cloud_args');
```

With the new wp 4.9 however the 'smallest' and 'largest' arguments do not have any effect. It invariably shows 8pt for the 'smallest' and 22pt for the 'largest' font-size. The only argument that has an effect is 'order' => 'RAND'. The rest is ignored. I tried to alter the values in the source file (category-template.php). But also this test had no effect. Does anyone have an information about this behaviour?
Thanks a lot for your interest. regards theo

Comment: Probably some plugins/theme interfering via filter, try another filter priority here, e.g. `add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args','set_widget_tag_cloud_args', 999 );`

Comment: @birgire – thanks for your answer, i already tried that one but sorry, priority has no effect

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
function my_custom_tag_cloud_widget( $args ) {
    $args['largest'] = 26;
    $args['smallest'] = 18;
    $args['format'] ='flat';
    $args['unit'] = 'px';
    $args['order'] = 'RAND';
    $args['separator'] = ' &bull; ';
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_custom_tag_cloud_widget', 999 );
```

Thanks for your interest. theo